# AJAX vs cURL for crawling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I trying to "get" a URL of www.gsmarena.com for scraping. The underlying HTTP GET request is working alright with PHP CURL code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

But I don't want to use PHP CURL. I want to do the same thing using JQUERY AJAX following codepen I created:

http://codepen.io/amigoo/pen/qZGmqq?editors=1111

But I am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: What you want to do will be extremely unreliable to the point of not being achievable in JS due to the Same Origin Policy - see the question I marked as a duplicate for a full explanation of the issue and workarounds. I would strongly suggest you stick with using cURL.

Comment: Any links where I can clarify the fact that  I am getting Same Origin Policy in AJAX while not in cURL?

Comment: Your error is making that clear already.

Comment: So how does cURL bypass this fact?

Comment: It's not that cURL bypasses it, it's that JS is blocked by security restrictions in place in all browsers.

Comment: No problem, glad to help